# Does CodeIgniter Query Builder protect against sql injection even in more complexed queries?

Tags: codeigniter-3, sql-injection

I know that using CodeIgniter's [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) should protect against SQL injection. The Manual says that it "allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system." But I'm not sure if by "values" they mean anything that goes through the Query Builder, or only values that are passed in simple stucture like : `$this->db->where('name', $name);`

For instance, if I use:

```
$this->db->select('student_id, concat(fname, " ",lname) as student_name');
$this->db->from('student');
$this->db->join('class_has_teacher',"student.class_id=class_has_teacher.class_id AND teacher_id=$teacher_id");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Would the `$teacher_id` in the JOIN condition also be escaped?

(In case it matters, I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `$teacher_id` would be escaped.